# How to display the multiple items in text box which are selected from drop down?

Tags: javascript

How could I display multiple items in my text box which are selected from combo boxes? I need the code for this in JavaScript.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="C1">Content1</option>
  <option value="C2">Content2</option>
  <option value="C3">Content3</option>
  <option value="C4">Content4</option>
  <option value="C5">Content5</option>
  <option value="C6">Content6</option>
  <option value="C7">Content7</option>
  <option value="C8">Content8</option>
  <option value="C9">Content9</option>
</select>
```